# VBA HTTP response text does not support Japanese

Tags: vba, rest, encoding, httprequest, cjk

I have a VBA program that sends REST API request and get response.

I use WinHttp.WinHttpRequest to send request but the response text does not support Japanese.

It means if REST server returns result with Japanese, HTTP response text in VBA will be strange characters (e.g. ?aa??a).

I tried to SetRequestHeader with Accept-Language = ja-JP, Charset = UTF-8...but it does not work.

Please help me to resolve this problem.

My code here:

```
Dim oHttp As WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
Set oHttp = New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
oHttp.Open "GET", "url", False
oHttp.SetRequestHeader "Accept",  "application/json"
oHttp.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
oHttp.SetRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer <token>")
oHttp.Send (sData)
Debug.Print oHttp.ResponseText
```

Thanks

Comment: How about [MCVE]?

Comment: I think it is more that VBA cannot display it. VBA does not support unicode, displaying those king of characters require to change the locale of the system.

Comment: @VincentG VBA stores a string as unicode binary in memory.

Comment: You may try to read a binary content `WinHTTP.ResponseBody` and convert it to the unicode.

Comment: @omegastripes are you sure? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/string-data-type

Comment: @VincentG Read about `ChrW()` e. g. [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/chr-function).

Comment: Is this actually a login based API or can some more information be shared? In line with @Vityata's comment. Even if is login based, where is your code so far?

Comment: I edited to add my code. please take a look

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for that: use ServerXMLHTTP instead of WinHttpRequest.